# Using JSoup to aggregate data

Tags: java, css-selectors, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm trying to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to fetch some content off of http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick. If you go to that page, you'll see that the way they organize the data is to present each "word type" (adjective, verb, noun) for the word *quick* as its own section, and each section contains 1+ lists of definitions.

To make things a little more complicate, each word in each definition is a link to yet another dictionary.com page:

```
quick
    adjective
        1. done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity...
        2. that is over or completed within a short interval of time
        ...
        14. Archaic.
            a. endowed with life
            b. having a high degree of vigor, energy, ...
    noun
        1. living persons; the quick and the dead
        2. the tender, sensitive flesh of the living body...
        ...
    adverb
        ...
```

What I want to do is use JSoup to obtain the word types and their respective definitions as a list of strings, like so:

```
public class Metadata {
    // Ex: "adjective", "noun", etc.
    private String wordType;

    // Ex: String #1: "1. done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity..."
    //     String #2: "that is over or completed within a short interval of time..."
    private List<String> definitions;
}
```

Thus the page actually consists of a `List<Metadata>`, where each `Metadata` element is a word type paired to 1+ definitions.

I was able to find the list of word types using a pretty trivial API call:

```
// Contains 1 Element for each word type, like "adjective", "noun", etc.
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick").get();
Elements wordTypes = doc.select("div.body div.pbk span.pg");
```

But I'm struggling figure out what are the othe necessary `doc.select(...)` I'll have to do to obtain each `Metadata` instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at HTML that Jsoup got from this page you will see something like

```
  <div class="body"> 
     <div class="pbk"> 
      <span class="pg">adjective </span> 
      <div class="luna-Ent">
       <span class="dnindex">1.</span>
       <div class="dndata">
        done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity, as an action, process, etc.; prompt; immediate: 
        <span class="ital-inline">a quick response.</span> 
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="luna-Ent">
       <span class="dnindex">2.</span>
       <div class="dndata">
        that is over or completed within a short interval of time: 
        <span class="ital-inline">a quick shower.</span> 
       </div>
      </div>
...
     <div class="pbk"> 
      <span class="pg">adverb </span> 
      <div class="luna-Ent">
       <span class="dnindex">19.</span>
       <div class="dndata">
        <a style="font-style:normal; font-weight:normal;" href="/browse/quickly">quickly</a>.
       </div>
      </div> 
     </div>
```

So every section

```
adjective
    1. done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity...
    2. that is over or completed within a short interval of time
    ...
    14. Archaic.
        a. endowed with life
        b. having a high degree of vigor, energy, ...
noun
    1. living persons; the quick and the dead
    2. the tender, sensitive flesh of the living body...
    ...
adverb
    ...
```

is inside `<div class="pbk">` which contains `<span class="pg">adjective </span>` with name of section and definitions in divs `<div class="luna-Ent">`. So you can try to do something like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick").get();

Elements sections = doc.select("div.body div.pbk");
for (Element element : sections) {
    String elementType = element.getElementsByClass("pg").text();
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println(elementType);

    for (Element definitions : element.getElementsByClass("luna-Ent"))
        System.out.println(definitions.text());

}
```

This code will select all sections and will find name of section using `element.getElementsByClass("pg")` and definitions using fact that they are in div that has class `luna-Ent` `element.getElementsByClass("luna-Ent")` (if you want to skip numbers `1.`, `2.` you can select `dndata` class instead `luna-Ent`)

Output:

```
--------------------
adjective
1. done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity, as an action, process, etc.; prompt; immediate: a quick response.
2. that is over or completed within a short interval of time: a quick shower.
3. moving, or able to move, with speed: a quick fox; a quick train.
4. swift or rapid, as motion: a quick flick of the wrist.
5. easily provoked or excited; hasty: a quick temper.
6. keenly responsive; lively; acute: a quick wit.
7. acting with swiftness or rapidity: a quick worker.
8. prompt or swift to do something: quick to respond.
9. prompt to perceive; sensitive: a quick eye.
10. prompt to understand, learn, etc.; of ready intelligence: a quick student.
11. (of a bend or curve) sharp: a quick bend in the road.
12. consisting of living plants: a quick pot of flowers.
13. brisk, as fire, flames, heat, etc.
14. Archaic. a. endowed with life. b. having a high degree of vigor, energy, or activity.
--------------------
noun
15. living persons: the quick and the dead.
16. the tender, sensitive flesh of the living body, especially that under the nails: nails bitten down to the quick.
17. the vital or most important part.
18. Chiefly British. a. a line of shrubs or plants, especially of hawthorn, forming a hedge. b. a single shrub or plant in such a hedge.
--------------------
adverb
19. quickly.
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. By the way, to test CSS selectors you may activate console in Chrome Developer tools and test queries like this directly on their site: `jQuery('div.body div.pbk div.luna-Ent > .dndata')`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick").get();
Elements wordTypes = doc.select("div.body div.pbk");

for (Element wordType : wordTypes) {
    Elements typeOfSpeech = wordType.select("span.pg");

    System.out.println("typeOfSpeech: " + typeOfSpeech.text());

    Elements elements = wordType.select("div.luna-Ent > .dndata");

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        Element element = elements.get(i);
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + element.text());
    }
}
```